# GridView Row Styling

Tags: .net, wpf, styles, radgrid

I want to make some rows in a `RadGridView` **Bold**;
I've set

```
<telerik:RadGridView.RowStyle>
   <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewRow">
      <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{Binding RowFontWeight}" />
   </Style>
</telerik:RadGridView.RowStyle>
```

and in `ItemsSource` object I've set the `RowFontWeight` value, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I think your `RowFontWeight` is not accessible in the `DataContext` of datagrid rows; I have used this style in past and works fine for me;

I am attaching a telerik sample, I modified this sample by adding a `RowFontWeight` property in model classes(`Club.cs` and `Player.cs`) and adding your style to datagrid; It works fine, parent grid rows become bold where as in child grid they become light.

[image]

[Download Sample](http://sdrv.ms/NMAPeT)