# Bind row style to property of usercontrol

Tags: wpf, styles, bind, radgridview

In a UserControl I have a property :

```
public FontWeight RowFontWeight { get { return FontWeights.Bold; } set { } }
```

And I have a RadGridView name mygv; in constructor of the usercontrol I've set

```
mygv.DataContext = this;
```

And in the gridview I have:

```
<telerik:RadGridView.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewRow">
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{Binding RowFontWeight}" />
     </Style>
</telerik:RadGridView.RowStyle>
```

but the rows don't change to Bold.
i've changed the propperty type to string and it didn't work again.
Obviously if I write ... Value="Bold" ..., it's ok.

Comment: You are `Binding` `FontWeight` to the `DataContext` of each row. I'm guessing you should do: `Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=RowFontWeight}"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [GridView Row Styling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223707/gridview-row-styling)